# File is saving but unable to load in Android

Tags: android, android-file, android-download-manager

I'm downloading html file from download manager. The file is downloading but is unable to load in the webview.

I guess there is some problem with the `PATH`.

**Download code**:

```
public void myDownload(String myURL, String title, String year, String branch, String section) {

  DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myURL));
  request.setTitle("File Download");
  request.setDescription("Downloading....");

  //request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
  request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
  request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
  String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myURL, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myURL));  

  request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/KiiTTimeTableData/" + year + "/" + branch + "/" + section + "/", nameOfFile);
  //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/sdcard/KiiTTimeTableData/" + year + "/" + branch + "/" + section + "/", nameOfFile);
  DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
  manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

---

**File Loading Code**:

```
File fMon = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/KiiTTimeTableData/" + year + "/" + branch + "/" + section + "/", "mon.html");
if (fMon.exists()) { //Check if file exists
  webView.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/KiiTTimeTableData/" + year + "/" + branch + "/" + section + "/" + "mon.html");
}
else {
  webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/not_found.html");
}
```

Comment: is giving you an error?

Comment: what do you mean by unable to load? some error?

Comment: @AshishRanjan Yes... webview is going to the else part because the file is not found. But the file is downloaded

Comment: you've read permissions in your manifest file, right?

Comment: Try making a `DownloadManager.Request setDestinationUri (Uri uri)`, refer here [setDestinationUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationUri(android.net.Uri))